# pig_hook in airflow doesn't work for python3

Tags: python-3.5, airflow

Using Python 3.5.2, airflow 1.9.0

Trying to set up a pig hook, looking at the documentation here:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py

following the example in lines 50-52

```
    >>> ph = PigCliHook()
    >>> result = ph.run_cli("ls /;")
    >>> ("hdfs://" in result)
```

Gives the following error:

```
  File "python3.5/site-packages/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py", line 53, in run_cli
f.write(pig)
  File "python3.5/tempfile.py", line 622, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If updated to run as:

```
    >>> ph = PigCliHook()
    >>> result = ph.run_cli("ls /;".encode('utf-8'))
    >>> ("hdfs://" in result)
```

The error becomes:

```
  File "python3.5/site-packages/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py", line 74, in run_cli
stdout += line
  TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

And later in the same pig_hook.py file it does assume a string type for this field, so I don't think passing the input as a bytes object is correct.

I believe the object causing the problem is NamedTemporaryFile (from line 52 in pig_hook.py) which is opened by default in mode 'w+b' as described in the following post:

https://bugs.python.org/issue29245

But if I change line 53 in pig_hook.py to read:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=tmp_dir,'w') as f:
```

or

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(dir=tmp_dir, mode='w') as f:
```

it still expects a byte array resulting in the same error:

```
  File "python3.5/site-packages/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py", line 53, in run_cli
f.write(pig)
  File "python3.5/tempfile.py", line 622, in func_wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? I can't seem to get NamedTemporaryFile to open in a mode that uses string, and the rest of the code assumes a string.

Comment: I *think* this might be connected in how Python 3 handles strings and a bug. Can you try Python 2?

Comment: I agree, and that's also what the bug report for NamedTemporaryFile (https://bugs.python.org/issue29245) indicates. Unfortunately this small script is part of a larger project, and the rest is written in Python 3. Luckily I can wrap the pig call in shell script and use Airflow's BashOperator with Python3, though I would much prefer if the Pig hook itself could work. I'm confused as to why the NamedTemporaryFile won't allow me to open with string mode, I feel like that's the only thing preventing this from working, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error after calling:

```
>>> ph = PigCliHook()
>>> result = ph.run_cli("ls /;".encode('utf-8'))
>>> ("hdfs://" in result)
```

which was

```
File "python3.5/site-packages/airflow/hooks/pig_hook.py", line 74, in run_cli
stdout += line
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Was not coming from my own input but from the logging. So I added:

```
line = line.decode('utf-8')
```

to line 75 of the pig_hook and it seems to be working just fine now.